# display greyed out link in php

Tags: php, mysql

Hi May I know how to display greyed out link when the event status is already over? My code is as below but when I put  the whole line of echo statement is not valid.

```
<?php if($row['Event_status'] = "Over")?>

                        echo "<td><a href='CustPortal.php?booking_id=".$row['Booking_id']."'> Cancel</a></td>";
```

Comment: where is the duplicate question ?

Answer (score 0):

You have closed php tag ?> and use == instead of =

try this

```
<?php
if($row['Event_status'] == "Over")
  echo "<td><a href='CustPortal.php?booking_id=".$row['Booking_id']."'> Cancel</a></td>";
?>
```

Comment: hi droid. it is working now but how to I create a greyout cancel link?

Comment: use style <a style="color:grey"

Comment: or css <?php
if($row['Event_status'] == "Over")
  echo "<td><a style='color:grey' href='CustPortal.php?booking_id=".$row['Booking_id']."'> Cancel</a></td>";
?>

Comment: hi droid it works but it allow me to cancel the booking. may I know how to make the grey link not cancellable.

Comment: I mange to find the solution! echo "<td><span style='color:grey' href='CustPortal.php?booking_id=".$row['Booking_id']."'> Cancel</span></td>"; ?>

Comment: remove href attribute it's for a tag, not span.